# Antistatic mat alternative

Tags: graphics-card, power-supply, computer-building

I'm going to replace the psu and graphics card for a computer, and I don't particularly want an antistatic wristband (I'll just slap a radiator), but when I'm opening it, what shall I put it on that won't risk it blowing up that I would have already?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this webpage](http://www.school-for-champions.com/science/static_materials.htm) wood is safe. Marble and related stone surfaces should also be safe.

Comment: Thanks - is there anything else obvious that I should be careful of?

Comment: Don't use a mix of stuff on the positive and the negative side of that table on the webpage. Apart from that, touching a radiator for a second every few minutes should also reduce any static electricity that might be building up. But then again, I always put mine on the carpet and have never had any problems at all.

Comment: Okay - would this count as "grounding" the computer, or would I need to do something else?

Comment: Actually, most computer cases are automatically grounded when you plug the PSU in (don't ask me how though). So they aren't electrically charged. (don't leave the cable plugged in when working on the pc!). But you shouldn't worry to much, just tapping the radiator is enough most of the time.